# Android pixels to dp from design

Tags: android

In design for my app I get for example:

Box width: 300pixels

So now I started coding in my app. I have only dp. How can I know what value to put for that box in my xml file. I found on internet that every phone size has different px to dp calculations.

So when I create Linearlayout (that represents my box) hoe much dp should i put?

Comment: I usually just map the pixels into density pixels (`10px` -> `10dp`) unless these sizes cannot be replaced with `match_parent` or `wrap_content`. E.g. I might have a container in a design file (like Figma file) that is 300px wide and has 16px of margins between the container and the phone frame (which would make the phone frame 332px wide) - in Android I would just set the width of the container to `match_parent` and `margin` as 16**dp**. No calculations needed.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the comment. If there is no better option you can write it answer so I can upvote and mark as best answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

`dp` stands for density independent pixels. This means that the android operating system will calculate the exact number of pixels to draw your box based on the density capability of the device, as long as you specify it as `300dp`.

You can read more about this on the android developer guides [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

Comment: Did you read the question? I have design in pixels and I need to decide. How many density pixels to put in the xml file.

Comment: did you read the answer? the term density indpendent means that you put the value in as dp and the os will work it out for you.

Comment: But what value I put if my designe says 100px. If I put 100dp, on xs size screen it is equal to 80px and on xl screen size it is equal to 120px (I am just adding some numbers to show what I mean). How do you know gow much dp to put. This 100px could be design made for xl mobile phones.

Comment: The size of the screen is going to be a problem regardless of dp. if the designer puts 300px, and the screen is only 240px wide, what would you do then? Usually we overcome this problem by having different designs for different screen sizes. and have breakpoints which determine which design is used - eg `sw360dp`, `sw700dp`, `sw1080dp` etc. let me find the link to the developer documentation around this too. it'll help your designer also.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources. This gives you background as to what is possible within the resources folder. Particularly table 2 on that page.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes and this one too